How to access uploaded files (Images and CVs) from another folder in a Next.js project?
I'm working on a project with Next.js, where I've created a folder with two subfolders: port and port2. This project is a portfolio, and in the port2 folder, I've inserted some values into a MySQL database. The database includes files like CVs and images. When I insert the image and CV, they are saved in MySQL but also in public/uploads/images and public/uploads/CV.
Now, when I open the port folder using the CLI with cd ../port, I have a page.tsx file that displays values from MySQL. However, when I execute port, I get incorrect values. The images and CVs are missing because the public/uploads/images and public/uploads/CV folders don't exist in port. How can I access the public/uploads/images and public/uploads/CV folders from port2 in port?
